# How to make tooltip for each character of a cell in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, tooltip

Is it possible to have different tooltip on mouse over of each character in a cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't understand the requirement. Which sense could have to display "x" tooltip over "x" charachter?

Probably you want to define *custom* tooltip for every character of the call? For example you have FBI in the cell and you want to display "Federal Bureau of Investigation" as the tooltip, but you want to display separately every word over every character (like "Federal" over "F")? In any way you can implement all by usage [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). You should just format the cell with as `span` elements with one `<span>` for every charackter.

```html
<span title="Federal">F</span><span title="Bureau">B</span>
<span title="of Investigation">I</span>
```

Comment: yes, my requirement is very close to your assumption. 

But the only change is, instead of character, i would require to display colored vertical bars (either green or red) for a character. I will get status as a boolean value from backend and if status is true , i need to display green bar otherwise red. But problem is there are around 20 status bars for different devices and on hover, we need to display device details along with its status value.

Comment: @RavishNV: I don't understand where you have an implementation problems. You should append the text of your question with an example of input data which you get. You need just set `title` attribute with the text of tooltip for every vertical bars which you place in the cell. Do you displays *multiple* bars in one cell? I used frequently separate columns with chechboxes for close grid. I set `title` for every *column* by usage `cellattr` property in `colModel`.